# How to show model state errors while saving data by calling ajax post

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

what i have tried in my action method is when the model state is not valid i redirect the view with the model data but it could not show the errors in view

```
public ActionResult Create(IndentmstViewData model)
{
    model.fk_sessionUserid = Session["userID"].ToString();
    model.fk_sessionLocid = Session["fk_locid"].ToString();
    model.pk_IndentId = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["EditId"]);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF - 8", "yes"),
           new XElement("XMLdata",
           from itemdet in model.GetItemDetails
           select new XElement("ItemDetails",
           new XElement("fk_itemid", itemdet.fk_ItemId),
           new XElement("qty", itemdet.Qty),
           new XElement("balqty", itemdet.indbalqty),
           new XElement("estimatedcost", itemdet.EstimatedCost),
           new XElement("partno", itemdet.PartNo),
           new XElement("itemdesc", itemdet.itemDesc),
           new XElement("fk_indentid", model.pk_IndentId))));

        model.doc = doc.ToString();

        if (model.pk_IndentId == 0)
        {
            _indent_mstService.Save(model.ADTO());
        }
        else
        {
            _indent_mstService.Update(model.ADTO());
        }

    }
    else
    {
        string fk_locid = Session["fk_locid"].ToString();
        model.IndentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Replace("-", "/").ToString();
        model.GetMenuData = GetMenuByUser();
        model.GetItems = _HomeService.GetItems().ToList();
        model.IndentNo = _indent_mstService.GetAutoIndentNo(fk_locid).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(model);
    }

    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

jQuery Ajax Post method is

```
$.ajax({
    url: $('#SaveDetails').val(),
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: "JSON",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        window.location.replace("http://addusharma.somee.com/Indent_mst/Create");
        alert("Record Save Successfully !!");
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("error");
        $('#form').empty();
        var result = $(Data).find('#form').html();
        $('#form').html(result);
    }
});
```

what i want to achieve is, when model state is not valid it should show the model errors in my view

Answer (score 0):

Ajax **error** function will be launched only if request failed. In your case controller returns success result in both cases. So you need to handle everything in **success** function.

```
success: function (data, text, xhr) {  
    if(xhr.hasOwnProperty('responseJSON')){
        window.location.replace("http://addusharma.somee.com/Indent_mst/Create");
        alert("Record Save Successfully !!");            
    }
    else{
        alert("error");
        $('#form').empty();
        var result = $(data).find('#form').html();
        $('#form').html(result);
    }                  
},
```

Answer (score 0):

To show the Validation Errors you need to use validation Summary in your view.

> @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

To know further about how to use ValidationSummary read [here](https://www.completecsharptutorial.com/asp-net-mvc5/html-validationsummary-example-tutorial-aspnet-mvc.php).

Answer (score 0):

> Controller

```
  public ActionResult Create(IndentmstViewData model)
    {
        model.fk_sessionUserid = Session["userID"].ToString();
        model.fk_sessionLocid = Session["fk_locid"].ToString();
        model.pk_IndentId = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["EditId"]);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF - 8", "yes"),
               new XElement("XMLdata",
               from itemdet in model.GetItemDetails
               select new XElement("ItemDetails",
               new XElement("fk_itemid", itemdet.fk_ItemId),
               new XElement("qty", itemdet.Qty),
               new XElement("balqty", itemdet.indbalqty),
               new XElement("estimatedcost", itemdet.EstimatedCost),
               new XElement("partno", itemdet.PartNo),
               new XElement("itemdesc", itemdet.itemDesc),
               new XElement("fk_indentid", model.pk_IndentId))));

            model.doc = doc.ToString();

            if (model.pk_IndentId == 0)
            {
                _indent_mstService.Save(model.ADTO());
            }
            else
            {
                _indent_mstService.Update(model.ADTO());
            }

            return JSON(new
            {
                ResultStatus=false,
                Message="Here Success Message Text...",
                Result=new 
                {
                    fk_sessionUserid= model.fk_sessionUserid,
                    fk_sessionLocid=model.fk_sessionLocid,
                    pk_IndentId=model.pk_IndentId,
                    Doc=model.doc
                }
            });

        }
        else
        {
            return JSON(new
            {
                ResultStatus=false,
                Message="Here Error Text...",
                Result=new 
                {
                    IndentDate= DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Replace("-", "/").ToString(),
                    GetMenuData= GetMenuByUser(),
                    GetItems=_HomeService.GetItems().ToList(),
                    IndentNo=_indent_mstService.GetAutoIndentNo(fk_locid).FirstOrDefault()
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

> JS

```
    $.ajax({
    url: $('#SaveDetails').val(),
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: "JSON",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        if(data.ResultStatus==true){
        window.location.replace("http://addusharma.somee.com/Indent_mst/Create");
        alert(data.Message);
        }else{
         alert(data.Message);       
        }

    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert(data.Message);
        $('#form').empty();
        var result = $(Data).find('#form').html();
        $('#form').html(result);
    }
});
```